# Element-wise addition of multiple sparse matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, python-3.7, sparse-matrix

I have a list of sparse CSR matrices of the same shape. I want to add them element-wise, so that the result matrix stays sparse.

Is there a better way than doing this in this kind of loop?

```
a = lil_matrix((5,5)).tocsr()

for m in m_list:
    a += m
```

I have also tried this aproach:

```
a = np.sum(m_list)
```

but I've read somewhere that numpy functions shouldn't be mixed with scipy sparse matrices, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's experiment:

Make some matrices:

```
In [30]: mlist = [sparse.random(5,5,.2,'csr')*10 for _ in range(3)]
In [32]: mlist = [(sparse.random(5,5,.2,'csr')*10).astype(int) for _ in range(3)
    ...: ]
In [33]: mlist
Out[33]: 
[<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
In [34]: [m.A for m in mlist]
Out[34]: 
[array([[0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
        [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
        [7, 0, 6, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
        [8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [7, 0, 8, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

Do the explicit addition (same as your loop):

```
In [36]: mlist[0]+mlist[1]+mlist[2]
Out[36]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [37]: _.A
Out[37]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  0,  8],
       [ 4,  0,  6,  0,  0],
       [15,  9,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  0, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Apply python's `sum':

```
In [38]: sum(mlist)
Out[38]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [39]: _.A
Out[39]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  0,  8],
       [ 4,  0,  6,  0,  0],
       [15,  9,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  0, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

and `np.sum`:

```
In [40]: np.sum(mlist)
Out[40]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [41]: _.A
Out[41]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  0,  8],
       [ 4,  0,  6,  0,  0],
       [15,  9,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  0, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Both work.  Python `sum` just iterates through the list, performing `+` between them.

`np.sum` makes an array:

```
In [42]: np.array(mlist)
Out[42]: 
array([<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

but since that's an object dtype array, it too delegates the task to the `+` method of the matrices.

Not too much difference in times:

```
In [43]: timeit sum(mlist)
421 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [44]: timeit np.sum(mlist)
391 µs ± 18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [45]: timeit mlist[0]+mlist[1]+mlist[2]
334 µs ± 629 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

But compare that with the addition of the dense arrays:

```
In [46]: timeit mlist[0].A+mlist[1].A+mlist[2].A
25.3 µs ± 505 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Sparse matrix addition is not very efficient.  The format is better for matrix multiplication, but even there the sparsity needs to be on the order of 10% or less.  I haven't testing addition against sparsity.

If you constructed those `csr` matrices from `coo` style inputs, you might look into combining the inputs first.  With `coo` style inputs, duplicate entries are summed.

Just to illustrate that idea:

```
def foo(mlist):
    data, row, col = [],[],[]
    for m in mlist:
        mc = m.tocoo()
        data.extend(mc.data)
        row.extend(mc.row)
        col.extend(mc.col)
    res = sparse.csr_matrix((data,(row,col)),shape=mc.shape)
    return res

In [55]: foo(mlist)
Out[55]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [56]: _.A
Out[56]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  0,  8],
       [ 4,  0,  6,  0,  0],
       [15,  9,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  0, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
In [57]: timeit foo(mlist)
738 µs ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

It's slower than the `sum` so I wouldn't do it retroactively.  But still it's an option to keep in mind.